# R formula interface: How to code splines on subset of explanatory variable?

Tags: r, regression, formula, spline

I am doing regression with R. Let us assume my response is called y and an explanatory variable x. For the sake of argument, assume x = 1...100. I know that my response behaves very differently on x=1...10 from x=11...100. This is why I would like to fit a regression spline on x=11...100 and something else, say a constant to x=1...10.

My question: How does one write such a formula for the R formula interface?

### What I tried so far

A brief example:

```
# some non-random data
set.seed(0815)
y = c(rpois(10,3), sapply(seq.int(1,90), function(lambda)rpois(1,lambda/10) ) )

# some explanation for this
x = seq_along(y)

# fit spline for all x, with df = 3, no problem but bad fit
m = glm(family = poisson(), formula = y ~ ns(x,df=3))

# failed naive approach
fac = ifelse(x > 10, 0, 1)
m_fail = glm(family = poisson(), formula = y ~ fac + ns(x[11:100], df=3) )
```

### What else does not work

There are two other possibilities I could think of, both work in the example but not for the real application.

1. Two separate fits: Just split x and y and call glm twice. Does not work since my real problem is multivariate and not all predictors split as x does.
2. Create a model matrix: My real problem has a few million observations. Creating explicit model matrices outside of glm takes a lot of time and RAM and is thus not feasible.

Comment: maybe this helps https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137986/fitted-model-of-linear-spline-regression-in-r

Comment: Dirk: I do not understand how this would help. The linked answer describes how to generate the spline basis functions. It is not related to the R formula interface. Please explain, if I misunderstood or overlooked something.